# How to have total from another table be part of my model in asp.net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, model

So it's possible that what I'm trying to do isn't possible in the way I'm trying to do it, but basically in my budget model I'm wanting to have the actual amount. This is basically the total of all transactions for that budget.  Maybe this needs to be calculated on the controller, but it seems cleaner if I could do it on the model. I'm using SQL server for my database and entity framework if that makes a difference.

In SQL I'm doing this search like this

```
Select budgetID, sum(amount) as 'Actual'
 From Transactions
 Group By budgetID
```

Also I'm having an issue with code accepting budgetID in transaction to be a foreign key. When I put that in there and try to update the database I'm told that The navigation property 'Budget' was not found on the dependent type 'BudgetApp.Models.Transaction'.

```
    public class Budget
{
    [Key]
    public int ID {get; set;}
    [Display(Name = "Budget" )]
    [Required]
    public string budgetName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Amount")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public double budgetAmount { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Month")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString ="{0:MMM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime budgetMonth { get; set; }
    public double budgetActual() {
        double actual = 0; //somehow get total here
        return actual;
    } 
}

public class Transaction
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime tranDate { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    [Required]
    public string tranDesc { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Amount")]
    public double amount { get; set; }
    //[ForeignKey("Budget")]
    public int budgetID { get; set; }

}

public class BudgetDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Budget> Budgets { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your `Budget` class would need to include `public virtual ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }` and then you could use a linq query to get the sum, but this should really be done in the controller, not the model.

Comment: Ok, so would it be best to then not have an actual in my budget class and then pass the actual amounts to the view separate from budget model?

Comment: I would recommend using a view model (say `BudgetVM`) with a `public double budgetActual { get; set; }` property and set its value in the controller (that property should not be included in a data model)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: What if the value of the actual budget should have been updated in the database everytime a transaction occurs? Is it a good idea to keep the total in the database? Or use the transactions directly and sum it up when needed?

Comment: You can use a transaction (or a trigger), but generally its not a good idea to store calculated values in a database field. Better to use `var total = db.Transaction.Where(t => t.budgetID == someValue).Sum(t => t.amount); to get the total when you need it. (and depending on how accurate you want it to be, you should consider using a `decimal` type rather than a `double`)